# customisation point for alias to std types

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup, customization-point, tag-invoke

Let's say I am writing some generic algorithm in `lib` namespace that calls a customisation point `my_func`.

First attempt is using ADL for `my_func`
one of the user wants to specialise `my_func` for his type, which is an alias to `std` type. Surely define it in his namespace won't work because ADL won't work for alias. Defining it in `std` namespace is not allowed by the standard. the only option left seems to define in the algorithm's namespace `lib`. But this doesn't work either if the end user includes the algorithm header before including the customisation header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// my_algorithm.hpp
namespace lib{

template<typename T>
void my_algorithm(const T& t){
    my_func(t);
}

} // namespace lib

// user1.hpp
namespace user1{

struct Foo1{
    // this is working as expected (ADL)
    friend void my_func(const Foo1&){
        std::cout << "called user1's customisation\n";
    }
};

} // namespace user1

// user2.hpp
namespace user2{

using Foo2 = std::array<int,1>;

// this won't work because Foo2 is actually in std namespace
void my_func(const Foo2&){
        std::cout << "called user2's customisation\n";
}

} // namespace user2

/* surely this isn't allowed
namespace std{
void my_func(const user2::Foo2&){
        std::cout << "called user2's customisation\n";
}
} //namespace std
*/

// another attempt to costomize in the algorithm's namespace
// this won't work because my_func isn't seen before my_algorithm
namespace lib{
    void my_func(const user2::Foo2&){
        std::cout << "called user2's customisation\n";
    }
}



// main.cpp
// #include "algorithm.hpp"
// #include "user1.hpp"
// #include "user2.hpp"
int main(){
    lib::my_algorithm(user1::Foo1{});
    lib::my_algorithm(user2::Foo2{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bfdP8s

Second attempt is using niebloids for `my_func`, which has the same problem as ADL.

Third attempt is using `tag_invoke`, which should have same problem as ADL, i.e.,

- customising in user namespace won't work because my type is an alias to `std` type
- customising in `std` isn't allowed
- customising in `lib` namespace depends on the order the header includes
  The first points seem to be true, but the last point isn't. This seems to work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// tag_invoke.hpp  overly simplified version
namespace lib_ti{

inline namespace tag_invoke_impl{

inline constexpr struct tag_invoke_fn{

template<typename CP, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) operator()(CP cp, Args&&... args) const{
    return tag_invoke(cp, static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
}

} tag_invoke{};

} // namespace tag_invoke_impl
} // namespace lib_to


// my_algorithm.hpp

// #include "tag_invoke.hpp"
namespace lib{

inline constexpr struct my_func_fn {
    
template <typename T>
void operator()(const T& t) const{
    lib_ti::tag_invoke(*this, t);
}

} my_func{};


template<typename T>
void my_algorithm(const T& t){
    my_func(t);
}

} // namespace lib

// user1.hpp
namespace user1{

struct Foo1{
    // this is working as expected (ADL)
    friend void tag_invoke(lib::my_func_fn, const Foo1&){
        std::cout << "called user1's customisation\n";
    }
};

} // namespace user1

// user2.hpp
namespace user2{

using Foo2 = std::array<int,1>;

// this won't work because Foo2 is actually in std namespace
void tag_invoke(lib::my_func_fn, const Foo2&){
        std::cout << "called user2's customisation\n";
}

} // namespace user2

/* surely this isn't allowed
namespace std{
void tag_invoke(lib::my_func_fn, const user2::Foo2&){
        std::cout << "called user2's customisation\n";
}
} //namespace std
*/

// another attempt to customise in the algorithm's namespace
// In ADL case, this does not work. But in this case, it seems to work. why?
namespace lib{
    void tag_invoke(lib::my_func_fn, const user2::Foo2&){
        std::cout << "called user2's customisation\n";
    }
}



// main.cpp
int main(){
    lib::my_algorithm(user1::Foo1{});
    lib::my_algorithm(user2::Foo2{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hsKbKE

**Why does this not have the same problem as the First one (raw ADL)?**

Forth attempt is using template specialisation, which seems to work normally as expected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>




// my_algorithm.hpp

namespace lib{

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct my_func_impl{
    //void static apply(const T&) = delete;
};

inline constexpr struct my_func_fn {
    
template <typename T>
void operator()(const T& t) const{
    using impl = my_func_impl<std::decay_t<T>>;
    impl::apply(t);
}

} my_func{};


template<typename T>
void my_algorithm(const T& t){
    my_func(t);
}

} // namespace lib

// user1.hpp
namespace user1{

struct Foo1{};

} // namespace user1

namespace lib{

template<>
struct my_func_impl<user1::Foo1>{
    void static apply(const user1::Foo1&){
        std::cout << "called user1's customisation\n";
    }
};

} //namespace lib



// user2.hpp
namespace user2{

using Foo2 = std::array<int,1>;

} // namespace user2

namespace lib{

template<>
struct my_func_impl<user2::Foo2>{
    void static apply(const user2::Foo2&){
        std::cout << "called user2's customisation\n";
    }
};

}



// main.cpp
int main(){
    lib::my_algorithm(user1::Foo1{});
    lib::my_algorithm(user2::Foo2{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r71x6c

---

What is the best way to write generic algorithms and customisation points and allow clients to customise for aliases for std types?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> one of the user wants to specialise `my_func` for his type, which is an alias to std type

This is the original sin, which is causing you all the pain. Type aliases in C++ are just *aliases*; they're not new types. You have a generic algorithm that uses a customization point, something like

```
// stringify_pair is my generic algorithm; operator<< is my customization point
template<class T>
std::string stringify_pair(K key, V value) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << key << ':' << value;
    return std::move(oss).str();
}
```

Your user wants to call this generic algorithm with a standard type, like

```
std::string mykey = "abc";
std::optional<int> myvalue = 42;
std::cout << stringify_pair(mykey, myvalue);
```

This doesn't work because `std::optional<int>` doesn't provide an `operator<<`.
It *can't possibly be made to* work, because your user doesn't *own* the `std::optional<int>` type and therefore can't add operations to it. (They can certainly *try*, physically speaking; but it doesn't work from a philosophical point of view, which is why you keep running into roadblocks every time you get (physically) close.)

The simplest way for the user to make their code work is for them to "take legal ownership" of the type definition, instead of relying on somebody else's type.

```
struct OptionalInt {
    std::optional<int> data_;
    OptionalInt(int x) : data_(x) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const OptionalInt&);
};
OptionalInt myvalue = 42;  // no problem now
```

---

You ask why `tag_invoke` doesn't have the same problem as raw ADL. I believe the answer is that when you call `lib::my_func(t)`, which calls `lib_ti::tag_invoke(*this, t)`, which does an ADL call to `tag_invoke(lib::my_func, t)`, it's doing ADL with an argument list that includes both your `t` (which doesn't really matter) *and* that first argument of type `lib::my_func_fn` (which means `lib` is an associated namespace for this call). That's why it finds the `tag_invoke` overload you put into `namespace lib`.

In the raw ADL case, `namespace lib` is *not* an associated namespace of the call to `my_func(t)`. The `my_func` overload you put into `namespace lib` is not found, because it isn't found by ADL (not in an associated namespace) and it isn't found by regular unqualified lookup either (because *waves hands vaguely* two-phase lookup).

---

> What is the best way to write generic algorithms and customisation points and allow clients to customise for aliases for std types?

Don't. The "interface" of a type — what operations it supports, what you're allowed to do with it — is under the control of the author of the type. If you're not the author of the type, don't add operations to it; instead, create your own type (possibly by inheritance, *preferably* by composition) and give it whatever operations you want.

In the worst case, you end up with two different users in different parts of the program, one doing

```
using IntSet = std::set<int>;
template<> struct std::hash<IntSet> {
    size_t operator()(const IntSet& s) const { return s.size(); }
};
```

and the other one doing

```
using IntSet = std::set<int>;
template<> struct std::hash<IntSet> {
    size_t operator()(const IntSet& s, size_t h = 0) const {
        for (int i : s) h += std::hash<int>()(i);
        return h;
    }
};
```

and then both of them try to use `std::unordered_set<IntSet>`, and then *boom*, ODR violation and undefined behavior at runtime when you pass a `std::unordered_set<IntSet>` from one object file to another and they agree on the name of `std::hash<std::set<int>>` but disagree on its meaning. It's just a huge can of worms. Don't open it.